# How to create macro to split columns and rows?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, rows

I have a long worksheet which include 3 columns:

Column A = Invoice number
Column B = Receive amounts
Column C - Pay amounts

Each number in column A need to split to two rows: Pay and Receive.
For Pay will take the associate number from column C
For receive will take associate number from column B

[image: Test excel]

Comment: If you look into powerquery, you can set your data up as a table, then inside of this table go to  powerquery or data(2016) tab > query from table , then in the window that appears select the last 2 columns and right click unpivot columns

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where is this powerquery? I have Office 2013

Comment: 2013 it is a free microsoft [add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=39379) - if a work machine check that you are allowed to install.

Comment: Sorry cannot install addins. Firewall restrictions etc...It is forbidden by a company policy. So is there any way to create the result just like my example?

Comment: You could enquire with your IT dept whether they will allow as is a microsoft not third party add-in.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data are in `Sheet1`, and we will let the splited data in `Sheet2`. Here is a simple solution:

```
Sub Split_Column()

Set st1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set st2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

j = 1
For i = 1 To st1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    st2.Cells(j, 1) = st1.Cells(i, 1)
    st2.Cells(j, 2) = "Pay"
    st2.Cells(j, 3) = st1.Cells(i, 3)
    j = j + 1
    st2.Cells(j, 1) = st1.Cells(i, 1)
    st2.Cells(j, 2) = "Receive"
    st2.Cells(j, 3) = st1.Cells(i, 2)
    j = j + 1

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you both. This is what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have created simple VBA code to split the rows into column from sheet1 to sheet2 of the Activeworkbook. you can modify the code as per need.

```
Dim sel As Range, b As Range
Dim rcount As Integer: rcount = 1
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A:C").Delete Shift:=xlDown
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set sel = .Range("A2:C" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count)
For Each b In sel.Rows
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(rcount, 1).Value = b.Value2(1, 1)
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(rcount, 2).Value = .Cells(1, 2).Value
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(rcount, 3).Value = b.Value2(1, 2)
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(rcount + 1, 1).Value = b.Value2(1, 1)
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(rcount + 1, 2).Value = .Cells(1, 3).Value
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(rcount + 1, 3).Value = b.Value2(1, 3)
rcount = rcount + 2
Next
End With
```